# Question on fields with trival Brauer group

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, brauer-group

A common proof that an algebraically closed field has  trivial Brauer group goes something like this:

> Take $D$ a finite central division algebra over $K$, where $K$ is an algebraically closed field. Then for any $d\in D$ the field $K[d]$ is properly defined and makes for a finite extension of $K$. $K$ only allows for trivial extensions, so $D=K$.

If I'm right, (please tell me if I'm not), the fact that $D$ is central does not play any role in this proof. So what we basically proved is: there are no finite division algebras over $K$, so in particular there are no finite **central** division algebras.

(I've noticed something similar  in a (different) proof where *algebraically closed* is replaced by $C_1$.)

I now have two questions.

**First:** Am I right in saying what I've said about the proof shown above?

**Second:** Are there examples of fields with a trivial Brauer group, which **do have** non-trivial finite (not central) division algebras over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct and yes, you don't need centrality here. See for instance Gille-Szamuely's book for a more precise treatment.

Essentially, you want to determine Brauer classes of central simple algebras over $k$ which split over a certain finite Galois extension $K/k$. But you know that each Brauer class contains an unique division algebra (up to isomorphism) over $k$. As you pointed out, there are no division algebras over $k$ except $k$ itself.

For an example of field with trivial Brauer group but still having a non-trivial division algebra over it, I'm not completely sure. Think about an algebraic extension $K$ of $\mathbf{Q}$ containing all the roots of unity; this has trivial Brauer group (a proof can be found in Serre's *Local fields*) but the field $\mathbf{C}$ is a division algebra over $K$ which is not central.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is not finite over $K$ or $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

To your second question. Take any finite field $F$ and a (non-trivial) finite field extension $F \subset K$. Then $K$ is a division algebra over $F$ which is not central.
For example we could take $F = \mathbb{F}_2$ and $K = \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2 + x + 1)$. However, the Brauer group of a finite field is trivial since every finite division algebra is a field (see the first chapter of Andre Weil's Basic Number Theory for a proof.)